# Using any plugin results in http 500 error (and only plugins)

Tags: plugins, ftp, 500-internal-error

I am working on a site that was previously made by someone else. Whenever I try to use a plugin (eg. Dropbox Backup & Restore, Reset WP) I get an http 500 error.[I made a backup using filezilla.]

**using any plugin results in http 500 error (and only plugins)**
troubleshooting
-htacces.bak (ftp) **x**
-PHP memory limit (ftp) **x**
-faulty plugins **x**
-permissions for folders (ftp) **x**
-corrupted core file (ftp) **x**
-host end issues - **contacted**

**I am at a loss here, and don't know what else to try. Now, it might be a fault on the hosting end, but I would really appreciate some input as to what else might be causing this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these :
go to dashboard >>updates>> reinstall wordpress

if still does not work
rename: plugins folder to "plugins-old" and create new empty plugin folder

if still does not work
try changing the theme

let me know how it goes

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string in the theme and a plugin was the issue as the host was running PHP 7.0. Thanks for the input